# BTRFS: corrupt node, bad key order

Tags: linux, arch-linux, btrfs

I cannot mount a BTRFS partition and the error is

```
BTRFS critical (device sdb2): corrupt node, bad key order: block=369396563968, root=1, slot=164
BTRFS critical (device sdb2): corrupt node, bad key order: block=369396563968, root=1, slot=164
BTRFS error (device sdb2) failed to read block groups
BTRFS error (device sdb2) open_ctree failed
```

I cannot mount this partition no matter what I do. None of the `btrfs` commands appear to work at all.

Mounting with either `-o recovery,ro` or `-o usebackuproot` gives this error.

```
mount -o usebackuproot /dev/sdb2 /mnt/t   
mount: /mnt/t: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Using `btrfs check --repair /dev/sdb2`:

```
ERROR: cannot open file system
```

Output of `btrfs fi show /dev/sdb2`

```
Label: none  uuid: d81d07ed-7307-4eb3-a7b1-468f2ab6eb1c
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 1.33TiB
    devid    1 size 4.03TiB used 1.36TiB path /dev/sdb2
```

Comment: "no matter what I do" - what have you tried?  what happened/what error message was displayed when you tried those things?   also, please add output of `btrfs fi show /dev/sdb2`.  All of this should be edited into your question (**not** in a comment).

Comment: Done. I cannot remember all the commands I ran, but most of them just reported that it cannot be opened.

Comment: That `btrfs fi show` mentions /dev/sdb3 - is sdb2 part of a larger pool?  a dead/corrupted drive in a larger pool?   what kind of "raid" level? mirrored (i.e. copies=2 or more), just striped, or experimental-do-not-use-except-for-testing btrfs raid5/6 emulation?  do you have /dev/sdb3 in your system? can you mount that?   does it contain what it should? (if the answer to either of these last two questions is ~ yes, then backup now!)

Comment: It was a typo because the machine is offline right now. It is supposed to say /dev/sdb2. It is only /dev/sdb2 with /dev/sdb1 being swap space and I cannot mount that.

Comment: Oh and there is no RAID here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `btrfs check --init-extent-tree /dev/sdb2` twice made it possible to mount.